# What is the difference between Sys.getenv() and getOption() in R?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm wondering about the difference between the R environment and R options. Specifically, what is the difference between the settings held in this place:

`Sys.getenv()`

vs. this place

`getOption()`

When calling each of them, I receive quite different settings but I can't figure out what the difference is on a conceptual level. What is each of these intended for? When deciding in which location to let the user store their API keys, which one is the better (safer, faster, more logical) place to store them in? Does either of these settings persist after closing R?

Comment: Environment variables have nothing to do with R options. Envvars are passed from process to child-process and include such things as `PATH` (where to search for executables), `HOME` (the directory used by many things as a "default starting place" for storage, shells, etc), `TERM` (for terminal character rendering), etc. The `getOption` function is only to set or read R options in the same session, they are not implicitly migrated to child R processes. Envvars are visible to any user on the same host, possible security concern; R options are not.

Comment: They can be used for similar purposes, but I think using an `options(...)` for many things that envvars are used for is a bit of an abuse of its intent (subjective, based on years of observing others' use of R options, and decades of using OS-level envvars).

Comment: Environment variables are maintained by the operating system, i.e. software outside of R, and exist independently of R whereas options are maintained by R and do not exist independently of R.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the best practice to store things like API keys would be in the .renviron file, right?